# How to display selected items with foreach loop or any other loop in php/wordpress

Tags: php, foreach

I am sorry but I searched for a long time and I haven't got the answer of my problem. Please help me. The issue is -

I have an array which I am looping through "foreach". It works absolutely fine. But I want to display predefined items with the loop. For example;

my loop is,

```
<?php
$info = array ('name', 'age');
if (isset ($info) ) {
  foreach ($info as $new_info) {?>

    <p><?php echo $new_info['name'] . ", " . $new_info['age']; ?></p>

<?php }} ?>
```

This outputs correctly as -

```
Name1, age1
Name2, age2
Name3, age3
Name4, age4
```

.... and so on. As this is dynamic, I want to display specific items with this. Like, I want to display only 2nd and 4th item (or any other) from this loop. So the loop should output only -

```
Name2, age2
Name4, age4
```

I really don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me? I am also new to PHP coding.

Comment: Which rule defines if an item needs to be printed? I'm sure that this array `$info = array ('name', 'age');` does not contain those printed samples. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question properly. My actual array is - `$info = ot_get_option('info', array())`

Comment: Dear Mehdi, sorry that I probably misunderstood things due to my limited knowledge in PHP programming. Today I managed to print my original array. Here it is -           
`
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
            [icon_desc] => Desc 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [icon_desc] => Desc 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 3
            [icon_desc] => Desc 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 4
            [icon_desc] => Desc 4
        )

) `

Comment: my question is if you always want to just print 2nd and 4th item in your array? because basically you can just `echo $info[1]['title']. ", ". $info[1]['icon_desc'];` as second item and then the 4th item `echo $info[3]['title']. ", ". $info[3]['icon_desc'];`. What is the problem with that? why do you need a loop?